# Kotlin Obtener el valor de un EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy trabajando con Kotlin ANKO programe una lista con textview y EditText cuyo nombre identificatorio lo puse en el TAG ya que no tengo el nombre de los campos. Es todo dinámico, en ese momento no conozco como se llama cada EditText, el dato lo tengo en una variable.

Mi problema es al intentar obtener el valor de ese EditText para guardarlo.

El código que genera el elemento es asi

```
 editText {
      hint = value --> ES EL VALOR ACTUAL EN LA DB 
      tag = col --> ESTA ES LA VARIABLE QUE TIENE EL NOMBRE POR EJEMPLO APELLIDO
      gravity = Gravity.END
      textSize = 18f
      isEnabled = estate
      textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START
}.lparams(width = 0, height = wrapContent)
{
   weight = 0.7f
}
```

Entonces al presionar el botón de guardar necesito recuperar el valor de cada EditText de la vista

Como el nombre de los campos los tengo guardados lo que hago es un FOR de los mismos e intentar traerme el valor del EDITTEXT correspondiente pero me da error, en realidad no me dice nada sino que me saca de la APP

```
for (col in columnNames){
  if (col != "ID") {
        var inputTestText = findViewWithTag<EditText>(col).text
  }
}
```

col => tiene el valor correspondiente, por ejemplo "apellido" pero cuando paso por esa línea directamente se va de la APP sin largar ningún error

Comment: Intenta mejorar el "for", la var inputTestText invocar antes

Comment: Disculpame Alexis no comprendo su mensaje. Lo que sucede es que genero la vista dinamicamente. Entonces ese for esta dentro del Button SAVE. Lo que me tira error es la línea esa, pero en realidad si lo debugeo no arroja un error detemrinado, sino más bien sale de la APP

Comment: Hola considera revisar el LogCat y agregar en tus preguntas el mensaje de error, principalmente el que inicia con "Caused by" para tener más información,s saludos.

Comment: Es que lo estoy revisando peor no larga error jajaja simplemene sale de la APP y del debug pero sin ningún mensaje. Lo primero que hice fue ver eso. Gracias !!!